# Query port number used by process in a docker container

Tags: networking, docker, mesos

I have 2 docker containers - one running a monitoring app and the other running a service, both running in the same network namespace with net=host. (Mesos runs all jobs with this parameter.)

The service can bind to a random port.
How can I query which port has the service  bound itself to, from the monitoring container?

I tried reading /proc/net/tcp, but that seems to be very complex. Is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: `docker inspect container_id`

Comment: I wouldn't know the container ID in advance. I have mounted the docker socket inside the monitoring container and can use docker APIs to query them. I have tried to query for port numbers exposed, however I only get the port numbers exposed for container not running with net=host.

Comment: Can you clarify please in which environment you're in? It seems to me that you're using a Mesos cluster? If so, do not use links as suggest below.

Comment: It's a mesos + aurora + coreos + docker cluster.

Answer (score 1):

So, if I understand correctly, the service binds to random ports? If so, why is that the case? I guess this is far from ideal, all services I use bin to a specific port when used in a container.

For example, if you have an app (started via Marathon) which binds to a port defined via an environment variable, you could set this environment variable when you start the container, and use the `BRIDGED` networking mode to let Mesos choose a port from its port range.

If you install Mesos DNS, you could use it to determine the IP/port combination from the application name. E.g. if the Marathon app name is *testapp*, the service name will be `testapp.marathon.mesos`.

See

- http://mesosphere.github.io/mesos-dns/docs/

Comment: I cannot choose bridged mode as mesos enforces host networking mode. I redesigned my app to use random ports so that I can run multiple instances of the service on the same machine. Now service discovery fails, because of this, as there is no way to know beforehand what port will the service bind to, in host networking mode.I am trying to find a solution using aurora as of now, when I am convinced aurora cannot handle it, I will explore more. Any suggestions are highly welcome. :)

Comment: I know nothing about Aurora, unfortunately. We're using CoreOS clusters with Marathon as a scheduler, and all our applications are run as Docker containers. Bridged networking works fine for us. Why do you see that only host networking works? is this a problem with Aurora?

Comment: "Note that we currently default to host networking when running a docker image, to easier support running a docker image as an Executor."
From: http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/docker-containerizer/

I am surprised as to how does marathon+mesos has bridged networking and aurora+mesos does not. Is it as simple as giving a --net=bridged when running a docker container in aurora?

Comment: Do you have a specific need for Aurora? If not, I'd suggest do try the Marathon Docker image and see if that makes things easier for you. As I said, I can't help you with question regarding Aurora/Docker configurations... Sorry.

Comment: Well, Tobi. I just ran an aurora job with --net=bridge, and it worked. And to say I was banging my head over this because I thought Mesos enforces this constraint.

Comment: I guess everyone has these moments :-) Great that you got it to work. Still, I'd recommend to have a look at Mesos DNS. Service Discovery is sooner or later a topic you'll probably need to take care of.

Comment: Will do. Do you have any idea how to pass the coreos_private_ipv4 to containers to allow them to connect to etcd?

Comment: I can't use that approach as I do not have access to the coreos IPv4 variables from aurora. What I do is run a 'ip route' command and get the default route, which is the docker0 ip and helps me connect to etcd.

Answer (score -2):

Use `link` for this:

```
docker run --name myService service

docker run --link myService monitoring
```

more info you can find here https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/

Comment: Any idea if they start the other way round? Meaning, the monitoring starts before myService?

Comment: This is a bad idea. Links are deprecated in Docker and definitely not the way to go in a Mesos setup.